# How to detect ping flood in java?

Tags: java, web-services, ping, flooding

I hava a Java web service and I would like to send an alert to an Android client if a lot of ping requests target that web service. Is there a method/library which can provide this thing in Java?(something similar to scapy lib from python)

Comment: this helps https://github.com/zml2008/netevents/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zachsthings/netevents/ping/PingListener.java ?

Comment: It offers a better idea on how to do that. But i find it somehow complicated for my purposes. I was wondering if there is maybe a simpler approach such as a library. Do you know something like that?  Is JPCAP suitable for this approach?

Comment: I have never worked on such a topic . so tried to find something online and got above github project